# Control Port telnet AUTHENTICATE without any password

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, authentication

As mentioned in [stem.torproject:](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#can-i-interact-with-tors-controller-interface-directly)

> If your torrc doesn't have a CookieAuthentication or HashedControlPassword then to authenticate you will simply call AUTHENTICATE after connecting without any credentials.

So I commented out both `CookieAuthentication 1` and `HashedControlPassword 16:E600ADC1B52C80BB6022A0E999A7734571A451EB6AE50FED489B72E3DF` in my torrc file.

Then I restarted Tor and tried to connect by just by issuing AUTHENTICATE, without any credential. But I got the following error:

> 515 Authentication failed: Password did not match HashedControlPassword value from configuration. Maybe you tried a plain text password? If so, the standard requires that you put it in double quotes.

My question is, How can I login without any credential? I am using Tor Browser Bundle 6.5 on my Windows 10.

-torrc-default file-

```
AvoidDiskWrites 1
Log notice stdout
SocksPort 9150 IPv6Traffic PreferIPv6 KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth
ControlPort 9151
ClientTransportPlugin fte exec TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\fteproxy --managed
ClientTransportPlugin obfs2,obfs3,obfs4,scramblesuit exec TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\obfs4proxy
ClientTransportPlugin meek exec TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\terminateprocess-buffer TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\meek-client-torbrowser -- TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\meek-client
#CookieAuthentication 1
#HashedControlPassword 16:E600ADC1B52C80BB6022A0E999A7734571A451EB6AE50FED489B72E3DF
```

Note: I tried both commenting out and removing both lines.

-torrc file-

```
Bridge obfs4 198.<omitted for public post> iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 37.<omitted for public post> iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 151.<omitted for public post> iat-mode=0
DataDirectory C:\Users\Sourav\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
GeoIPFile C:\Users\Sourav\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\Sourav\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6
HiddenServiceStatistics 0
UseBridges 1
```

Still getting:

> 250-PROTOCOLINFO 1
>
> 250-AUTH METHODS=HASHEDPASSWORD
>
> 250-VERSION Tor="0.2.9.9"
>
> 250 OK

Screenshot of Tor data directory:

[image: screenshot tor data directory]

I have also tried `AUTHENTICATE ""`but failed.

[image]

Comment: Where did you comment them out?

Comment: in `torrec-defaults`. I know this is not recommended because this file may get overwritten during Tor upgrade. but I was just trying things out. `CookieAuthentication 1` was already present there. I commented it out first and added `HashedControlPassword 16:E600ADC1B52C80BB6022A0E999A7734571A451EB6AE50FED489B72E3DF` and it worked fine. authenticated using the password. then I commented out that line too.

Comment: It should work, some authentication is definitely being defined somewhere. What happens if you send it `PROTOCOLINFO` instead of `AUTHENTICATE`? It should give back a line saying `250-AUTH METHODS=NULL`, and have you accidentally defined some in `torrc` which is being applied after `torrc-defaults`?

Comment: @canonizingironize edited the question with additional info. Is there any chance that they apply default authentication method to `HashedControlPassword `? I have also posted a screenshot of Tor data directory. No other config file is there.

Comment: No, the default is definitely with no authentication, the manual has a big warning about that and I have tested it. Are you starting Tor by running the Tor Browser itself or running `tor.exe` from the command line or something?

Comment: also ftr `HiddenServiceStatistics 0` does nothing at all in your case, useless option to set.

Comment: @canonizingironize I didn't set `HiddenServiceStatistics 0`. It was there after installing. I didn't change. did you test `AUTHENTICATE` on windows machine?

Comment: I don't have a windows box to test on, but A) That's how Stem does it and Stem works on windows and B) The spec says it's fine and C) https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/control.c#n1263 the code says it's fine. `PROTOCOLINFO` says it thinks there's a hashed password set, thats going to be the root of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

set `CookieAuthentication 0`
if you had `HashedControlPassword` removed it

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 9051
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
AUTHENTICATE
250 OK
```

Answer (score -1):

The working syntax for null authentication to the control port is as:

authenticate ""

[Edited : The documented syntax which you tried, just authenticate, without parameters, is not accepted by Tor (depending on versions) ]

Comment: PROTOCOLINFO still shows `250-AUTH METHODS=HASHEDPASSWORD` and I tried your solution too but didn't work. It showed "515 Authentication failed: Password did not match HashedControlPassword value from configuration"

Comment: Incorrect, simply sending `AUTHENTICATE` is still entirely valid and works. Maybe you should try dong a simple test first?

Comment: I wouldn't write a thing I haven't checked and verified. I have been running successive versions of Tor on Windows assiduously for ca 15 years, and issuing auth and other commands thru the control port for as much time. AUTHENTICATE by itself would work in the good ol'days, but it ceased working at some point in the past, givng the exact error reported by the OP. I found experimnentaly the workaround in above ANSWER. Has worked for me since. Other versions/platforms maybe different

Comment: Amendment : it does differ by Tor versions, even on Windows. Just checked current 0.3.0.3-alpha, indeed AUTHENTICATE is accepted with a blank argument again. But it was not for several earlier versions, I had to edit my (a lot of) scripts for this so... depending on which exact tor the OP is using, he might try the proposed solution.

Comment: Tell me a version that doesn't accept it on Windows :)

Comment: Comments are not a place for arguing I think. Please PM me for this.

Comment: There is no PM on stackexchange :) Please provide a version where this happens under Windows, it sounds like you've encountered a bug in Tor that's apparently been around for years and should be fixed as it must already be breaking a lot of software.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood your query for a pointless argument, my bad really. Unfortunately i don't archive older Tor versions which I had been using locally. Judging from the "modified" date of a few shortcuts I have on my Windows "desktop" - designed to launch "netcat" as a poor man's Tor controller - the aforementioned problem with older script versions  /might/ have been noticed circa 2015, november. Sorry I can't tell which precise version(s) had that small problem, not even if they were the "alpha" or the regular Tor, or both,