# configuration to run tor as relay, crashing tor browser in windows

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, relays, windows

My experience of using tor on a windows machine is not good ([see this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14146/)). I have successfully used tor as a [relay](https://atlas.torproject.org/#search/70DFDD349F3C11228F638D0E993D910208A7E108) on my Linux virtual machine (just to test how it works) and it worked fine. So, I know how to edit the torrc file to set up a relay.

I recently tried to set up the relay on my host windows machine. So, I added the following lines to my torrc file.

```
ORPort 3195
Exitpolicy reject *:*
Nickname testrelay3195
ContactInfo human@yopmail.com
```

But, I am getting an error pop-up. There is also no(0) entry in the log file to debug the problem.

> Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor Browser will not start.

If I remove the lines, Tor starts normally.

Any idea, what is going on?

Comment: Are any of the ports already in use?

Comment: No. I have checked with netstat.